# Rails exception tracking for offline applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, exception

I'm aware of the existence of exceptional, airbrake, errbit etc. however I got some costumers which do not have access to my errbit server or to the internet and I want to be capable of get an organized collection of exceptions occurred on their installation, I'm thinking here more on a solution where and admin can login and see a view error data, how can I achieve this without rolling my own code or installing an errbit server per deployment?, Is there any engine or gem hooked to rails active support notifications which solves my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gem 'exception_notification' which send you an email when an error occurs. It would work for the clients with Internet access.